# How submit form with two buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 buttons (type submit) and one form.

How to realize submit form?
the user can click on two different button and submit form.

Comment: What is the problem here? Can we see your code to know where you are stuck please?

Comment: Umm. You do what you just said? What's the problem?

Comment: Both submit buttons will submit the form. That's what they do.

Comment: Please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can add as much submit buttons as you want

Comment: what are you trying to ask.Please frame the question in a better way and what is the problem in submitting using 2 buttons>share your code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below given example a user can either click on SUBMIT1 or on SUBMIT2 , each submit button will submit the relative form , for example SUBMIT1 will submit the 1.htm where as the SUBMIT2 will submit the 2.htm.

```
<html>
<div>
   <div id="1">
      <form action="1.htm">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT1">
      </form>
   </div>
   <div id="2">
      <form action="2.htm">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT2">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Just place the submit button inside the form you want to submit on its click .